# Is there some sort of functionality in Java that converts a char into a bit?

Tags: java, encoding, binary, bit

I'm trying to find a way to convert a char (Precondition is the char can only be '0' or '1') into an actual bit in Java. I'm not sure if Java has some built-in functionality for this, or if there is an algorithm that can be implemented to do so.

I need to implement the following class:

```
public void writeBit(char bit) {
//PRE:bit == '0' || bit == '1'
    try {
    
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

I cannot change the method structure in any way. I am implementing Huffman Encoding and have an array of Strings that represent the encodings for every character within an input file. For example, 'A' or array[65] contains the String: "01011". So if I see the letter A in my file, I need to use writeBit to write out A's respective String to a binary file. Every time I reach 8 bits (one byte) I will call writeByte to send those 8 bits to the binary file, then reset some sort of counter variable to 0 and continue.

What I'm stuck on is how I am supposed to convert the char bit into an actual bit, so that it can be properly written out to a binary file.

Comment: Huh, I don't get it. What is your expected result? Input? Output?

Comment: @Darkman I'll add more detail to the question. I apologize

Comment: You need a class with a class level variable that keeps track of the bits that have accumulated and eventually flushes the resultant byte to file

Comment: If you want to store ASCII characters in 5 bits, that means the uppercases and lowercases will be the same right? Something like this `('A' - 0x60) & 0x1F` == `('a' - 0x60) & 0x1F`.

Answer (score 0):

Java does not have a primitive data type representing a single bit.  On many hardware architectures, it is not even possible to access memory with that granularity.

When you say "an actual bit", then, I can only assume that you mean an integer value that is either `0` or `1`, as opposed to `char` values `'0'` and `'1'`.  There are numerous ways to perform such a conversion, among them:

- `byte the_bit = bit - '0';`.  This takes advantage of the fact that `char` is an integer type, and that the decimal digits zero and one are encoded in Java with consecutive character codes.
- `byte the_bit = (bit == '0') ? 0 : 1;`.  This just explicitly tests whether `bit` contains the value `'0'`, evaluating to `0` if so or `1` if not.

It gets more complicated from there, for example:

- `byte the_bit = Byte.parseByte(String.valueOf(bit));`.  This converts the `char` to a string containing (only) that char, and then parses it as the string representation of a byte.

All of the above rely to one degree or another on the precondition given: that `bit` does not have any value other than `'0'` or `'1'`.

---

With that said, I think anything like this is probably the wrong approach for implementing a Huffman encoding, because Java `String`s are an unlikely, very heavyweight, representation for the *bit* strings involved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Integer.parseInt(String s, int radix)` or `Integer.parseUnsignedInt(String s, int radix)` with radix `2`, to convert from a "binary digits string" to internal `int` java integer form.

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num = Integer.parseInt("101010", 2);
    // print 42
    System.out.println(num);
  }
```

And reversely with method `Integer.toBinaryString(int i)` you can generate the binary string representation:

```java
  // print 101010
  System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(42));
```

Similarly you can use `Byte.parseByte(String s, int radix)` to parse a byte:

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte num = Byte.parseByte("101010", 2);
    // print 42
    System.out.println(num);
  }
```